# IDIBU / LINKEDIN ERROR

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to post jobs from Idibu onto Linkedin. It's been working for a long time but suddenly on Friday (02/02/2018), I get an error.

After contacting Idibu and Linkedin, they advised me to post a message on here.

Error Code:

```
job identifier: 1858414_
status: FAIL
1858414array (
0 => '3ab2bd03-1e32-482e-8965-a79a07997aab',
)
Using key TCzaHpd1TWgGvNVw6qxnC0Pp8N9OBHV3F1p0xW_spLODYKr1mIA0aSaPSdjB2WN9
token: 3ab2bd03-1e32-482e-8965-a79a07997aab

Job was added to the database but error occured during posting to linkedin:
Internal service error
array (
'status' => '500',
'timestamp' => '1517585944663',
'request-id' => 'UA9WGL98JP',
'error-code' => '0',
'message' => 'Internal service error',
)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<share>
<comment><![CDATA[HR Assessor / Trainer, London, £29500 - £34000 per annum,         Education & Training]]></comment>
<content>
<title><![CDATA[HR Assessor / Trainer, London, £29500 - £34000 per annum,     Education & Training]]></title>
<submitted-url>http://idi.to/5iNV<;/submitted-url>
<submitted-image-url><!    [CDATA[https://www.aptrack.co/uap/logos/linkedin_status.jpg]]>;</submitted-image-url>
<description><![CDATA[KM Recruitment is a specialist UK wide recruiter for the Work Based Learning and Welfare to Work sectors.

Job Title: HR Assessor / Trainer

Location: London -..]]></description>
</content>
<visibility>
<code>anyone</code>
</visibility>
</share>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: What do you mean by "they advised" you?

Comment: I wonder if readers may not be able to help. An error of "Internal service error" is the vaguest possible error, and the real error will be in internal LinkedIn API logs. I think this needs to be logged with LinkedIn customer/developer services.

Comment: I logged it with Linkedin Support and they told me to come here as its got nothing to do with them apparently... They told me to come on here? Why I don't know?

Answer (score -1):

We were experiencing 'Internal API server' errors for weeks in October during profile requests.  Persistent questions to enterprise support resulted in a similar suggestion (look on stackoverflow), but I kept at it and was finally told that we had identified a "java bug".

No further explanation and a few weeks later I was notified that a fix would be released soon. After that, the issue seemed to stop, but we're now seeing a new spike in the same type of errors.

OAuth2 Error Occurred: : =0A{=0A "errorCode": 0,=0A "message": "Internal API server error",=0A "requestId": "(removed)",=0A "status": 500,=0A "timestamp": 1518103930225=0A}